# Arrays of semaphore and mutual assignment in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, semaphore

I am trying to use semaphores in C.

I have global variable: `sem_t array[5];'

And local `sem_t MyArray[2];` in a function.

I initialise my semaphores.

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    sem_init(&array[i], 0, 1);
```

I want to assign 2 of 5 semaphores from array to MyArray. So `MyArray` and `MyArray+ 1` will be for instance `array+3` and `array+1` and this are the same addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of a copy, try using pointers to the originals

```
sem_t* MyArray[2];
```

then just assign  `MyArray[0]  = &array[1];`    or whatever one you want

then use it like   `sem_wait(MyArray[0]);`    this is different than your original `array` which would be `sem_wait(&array[1]);`   because the MyArray is already pointer based.

Answer (score 3):

The semantics of assigning or copying a `sem_t` object is unclear without knowing the internals of `sem_t`.

- If `sem_t` is a simple handle or pointer, then simply taking a copy, both copies will refer to the *same* semaphore.
- If `sem_t` is a POD structure, taking a byte-by-byte copy is possible but the copy would be a *different* and *independent* semaphore.
- If `sem_t` is not POD and contains pointers, copyinmg is non-trivial.

What you probably really want is for `MyArray` to *refer* to `array` by being of type `sem_t*`:

```
// By initialisation
sem_t* MyArray[2] = { &array[3], &array[1] } ;
```

---

```
// By assignment
sem_t* MyArray[2] ;

MyArray[0] = &array[3] ;
MyArray[1] = &array[1] ;
```